# Create a relation in Parse Server on afterSave method in cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

So when I create an object in Parse Server, in the cloud code I am trying to link it to a user. At the moment I am doing something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("MyObject", function(request, response){
   var user = request.user;
   var relation = user.relation("myobjects");
   relation.add(request.object)
   user.save()

   response.success();
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work, It doesn't create the User column in the MyObjects table.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks